# Pandas want to change column data into serial number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I want to change the "Dut" column into a serial number following the number of each "ITEM"

There are lots of "ITEM"s. So I want to get the number of each item.

as following question
[image]

Input data:

```
data = {'ITEM': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
        'Dut': ['None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None', 'None'],
        'Stat.1': [37, 84, 54, 62, 89, 30, 74, 25, 30, 57, 34, 56, 78, 64]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby_cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

> If i want to "Dut" Column data as Dut1,Dut2...Dut9 @ "Item" a not, just nubmer how to change it?

```
df['Dut'] = 'Dut' + df.groupby('ITEM').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print(df)

# Ouput
   ITEM   Dut  Stat.1
0     a  Dut1      37
1     a  Dut2      84
2     a  Dut3      54
3     a  Dut4      62
4     a  Dut5      89
5     a  Dut6      30
6     a  Dut7      74
7     a  Dut8      25
8     a  Dut9      30
9     b  Dut1      57
10    b  Dut2      34
11    b  Dut3      56
12    b  Dut4      78
13    b  Dut5      64
```

Comment: Really thank you. If i want to "Dut" Column data as Dut1,Dut2...Dut9 @ "Item" a not, just nubmer how to change it?

Comment: @888Seeme. Glad to help. I updated my answer related to your comment. Can you check it please? If you want to pad with leading 0 (Dut01, Dut02, ... Dut11), you can also append `.str.zfill(2)` after `astype(str)`

Comment: You're so Angle... I saw Shine on your back... really Thx :))))))